# CPP within Haddock

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, haddock

I can change haddocks based on a flag if I put the entire block within the CPP conditional branches:

```
#if SOME_MACRO
-- | Whether SOME_MACRO is true
-- >>> someMacro
-- True
someMacro :: Bool
someMacro = macroVal
#else
-- | Whether SOME_MACRO is true
-- >>> someMacro
-- False
someMacro :: Bool
someMacro = macroVal
#endif
```

And the documentation looks as you'd expect it to, and `doctest` also works as expected.

But that's maintenance nightmare for larger comments or code blocks. On the other hand, this does not seem to work:

```
-- | Whether SOME_MACRO is true
-- >>> someMacro
#if SOME_MACRO
-- True
#else
-- False
#endif
someMacro :: Bool
someMacro = macroVal
```

Why is that? Isn't CPP processed before Haddock? I have the intuition that it's because a newline is staying on after the CPP stage, but it's just an intuition

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember if, as you say, a newline is inserted or if -- worse -- some `#line` directive is also inserted, which breaks the Haddock block.

Anyway, I think one could workaround it as follows:

```
#if SOME_MACRO
#define SOME_MACRO_HK -- True
#else
#define SOME_MACRO_HK -- False
#endif


-- | Whether SOME_MACRO is true
-- >>> someMacro
SOME_MACRO_HK
someMacro :: Bool
someMacro = macroVal
```

Insert newlines in the macro as needed, possibly integrating the whole Haddock block in it. Not elegant by any stretch, but it should do.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try a variant of this that defines a CPP function that takes to args, a string one for each GHC version, since that would look much nicer. I'll report back!